# Why I'm getting this, org.xml.sax.SAXParseException, exception?

Tags: java, xml, saxparser, openbravo

I'm working in `OpenBravoPOS v2.30`, anyone knows about it? It's a POS with free licence.
I'm trying to improve it, but in one of my test computers, it fails.

Before all, I'd read about similar cases in stackoverflow, but they were helpless.

Here's the full exception output:

```
WARNING: Analysis error. Invalid XML file.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:174)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:388)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1427)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1056)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:522)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:395)
    at com.openbravo.pos.sales.JTicketLines.<init>(JTicketLines.java:70)
    at com.openbravo.pos.sales.JTicketLinesMRB.<init>(JTicketLinesMRB.java:22)
    at com.openbravo.pos.sales.JRefundLinesMRB.loadTicketLines(JRefundLinesMRB.java:97)
    at com.openbravo.pos.sales.JRefundLines.<init>(JRefundLines.java:42)
    at com.openbravo.pos.sales.JRefundLinesMRB.<init>(JRefundLinesMRB.java:44)
    at com.openbravo.pos.sales.JTicketCatalogLinesMRB.newRefundLines(JTicketCatalogLinesMRB.java:23)
    at com.openbravo.pos.sales.JTicketCatalogLines.<init>(JTicketCatalogLines.java:48)
    at com.openbravo.pos.sales.JTicketCatalogLinesMRB.<init>(JTicketCatalogLinesMRB.java:17)
    at com.openbravo.pos.sales.JPanelTicketEditsMRB.getSouthComponent(JPanelTicketEditsMRB.java:52)
    at com.openbravo.pos.sales.JPanelTicket.init(JPanelTicket.java:272)
    at com.openbravo.pos.sales.JPanelTicketEditsMRB.init(JPanelTicketEditsMRB.java:77)
    at com.openbravo.pos.forms.JRootApp.getBean(JRootApp.java:409)
    at com.openbravo.pos.forms.JPrincipalApp.showTask(JPrincipalApp.java:378)
    at com.openbravo.pos.forms.MenuPanelAction.actionPerformed(MenuPanelAction.java:46)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at org.jdesktop.swingx.JXHyperlink.fireActionPerformed(JXHyperlink.java:244)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6055)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2039)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4653)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4236)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4166)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2083)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2482)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4481)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:648)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:607)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:605)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:621)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:619)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:618)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

It points at that line of code:

```
private static SAXParser m_sp = null;
 public JTicketLines(String ticketline) {

        initComponents();

        ColumnTicket[] acolumns = new ColumnTicket[0];

        if (ticketline != null) {
            try {
                if (m_sp == null) {
                    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                    m_sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                }
                ColumnsHandler columnshandler = new ColumnsHandler();
                m_sp.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(ticketline)), columnshandler);
                acolumns = columnshandler.getColumns();

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException ePC) {
                logger.log(Level.WARNING, LocalRes.getIntString("exception.parserconfig"), ePC);
            } catch (SAXException eSAX) {
                logger.log(Level.WARNING, LocalRes.getIntString("exception.xmlfile"), eSAX);
            } catch (IOException eIO) {
                logger.log(Level.WARNING, LocalRes.getIntString("exception.iofile"), eIO);
            }
        }

        initColumns(acolumns);

    }
```

Why it throws me that exception? It's a problem of the XML file? It's supposed to be the same XML at the different computers.

LoadTicketLines :

```
protected void loadTicketLines(DataLogicSystem dlSystem) {
        ticketlines = new JTicketLines(dlSystem.getResourceAsXML("Ticket.Line"));
    }
```

And the XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- 
    Openbravo POS is a point of sales application designed for touch screens.
    Copyright (C) 2007-2009 Openbravo, S.L.
    http://sourceforge.net/projects/openbravopos

    This file is part of Openbravo POS.

    Openbravo POS is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
    it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
    the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
    (at your option) any later version.

    Openbravo POS is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
    but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
    MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
    GNU General Public License for more details.

    You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
    along with Openbravo POS.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.
 -->

<line>

<!--    <column name="label.item" width="125" align="left" value="&lt;html&gt;#if ($ticketline.isProductCom()) &lt;i&gt;*&amp;nbsp;&amp;nbsp;${ticketline.printNameAndDiscount()}&lt;/i&gt; #else ${ticketline.printNameAndDiscount()} #end&lt;br&gt;${ticketline.getProductAttSetInstDesc()}"/>   -->

    <column name="label.item" fontsize="16" width="125" align="left" value="${ticketline.printName()}"/>

    <column name="label.units" fontsize="16" width="50" align="right" value="x${ticketline.printMultiply()}"/>
<!--  PARTY -->
<column name="label.pvp" fontsize="16" width="50" align="right" value="${ticketline.printPVP()}"/>
<column name="label.discount" fontsize="16" width="50" align="right" value="${ticketline.printDicountPercent()}"/>
<column name="label.TotalLine" fontsize="16" width="80" align="right" value="${ticketline.printValue()}"/>
</line>
```

Sorry if it contains a lot of code, dont know how to explain it better

Comment: What is `ticketline`? The stacktrace is telling you that it encountered a `Premature end of file`, so I would look at the XML as it is probably not well-formed.

Comment: Might SAXParser cause the problem since it is declared as static? What  code is around this?

Comment: i'll modify my question to show the XML

Comment: I tried to remove the static declaration and still doesn't work.
But at least thanks to try to help.

Comment: As @Kuchi pointed out, SAXParser isn't thread safe.. it probably should be a local variable.  But from your usage, I don't think that's the issue since it appears you're constructing a new JTicketLines for each XML file.  Your XML is well-formed so not sure what's happening.  Are you absolutely positive that's the XML that's getting fed to the parser?  Are you dumping it out somewhere or are you assuming that the code loading it is returning that file as is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I work in OpenBravoPOS too, and I think you're wrong to think that this is the XML where you get the error.

Look at the `Ticket.LineRefund` not at `Ticket.Line` to see if you have the error there.

Sorry if I am too late.